# How do I create a dashboard that searches other dashboards for recently modified or updated dashboards in Splunk?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dashboard

So I was just wondering if it was possible to create a simple xml or html code that has dashboard that searches for all other recently modified or updated searches of dashboards in splunk?

And if so when I search up these updated databases I would like to know the indexes and dataset that these dashboards have.

**Requested Table format**
Dashboard Name,  Index, Timestamp (Shows when the dashboard was last updated)

Hopefully that makes sense..Please let me know if it's possible, or similar ways I can find this! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could search

"_audit" index :

`index=_audit | table _time user action info`

```
index=_internal
```

The "_internal" index also has some sources on which to do username analytics ie:searches.log